# Modify the object that is pushed in an array when using an array.push that calls a function in Angular/JavaScript *array.push(function(parameter))*

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

How can I append the object that is pushed into the array, when using a function in the push method of the array (I hope I am wording it correctly)?

I have the following method that finds a match between a profile.id and a keywordId, and then pushes the matching kewordId into an array. **How can I append this push method to return a modified object and not only the keywordId?**

I would like to have the following pushed into the array:

`array.push({ id: profile.id, keyID: keywordID, name: profile.name });`

But I am not sure how to append this line to enable this:

`array.push(findKeywordProfile(profile.id));`

**This is my method that creates the array:**

```
function getKeywordProfiles(brandProfilesArray) {
  var array = [];
  brandProfilesArray.forEach(function (profile) {
      array.push(findKeywordProfile(profile.id));
  })
  return $q.all(array);
}
```

**This is the method called during the array.push function:**

```
function findKeywordProfile(brandProfileID) {
  var keywordProfileID = $q.defer();
  pullSocialMediaData('list_keyword_profiles.json').then(function (data) {
      var keywordProfileInstance = data.filter(function (keyword) {
          return keyword.brand_profile_id === brandProfileID;
      });
      keywordProfileID.resolve(keywordProfileInstance[0].id);
  });
  return keywordProfileID.promise;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the entire object in your function `keywordProfileID`

Something like,

```

```
function findKeywordProfile(brandProfileID) {
  var keywordProfileID = $q.defer();
  pullSocialMediaData('list_keyword_profiles.json').then(function (data) {
      var keywordProfileInstance = data.filter(function (keyword) {
          return keyword.brand_profile_id === brandProfileID;
      });
      keywordProfileID.resolve({id: keywordProfileInstance[0].id, name: keywordProfileInstance[0].id, keyID: keyword});
  });
  return keywordProfileID.promise;
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object from properties of `keywordProfileInstance[0]`, pass the object to `resolve()`

```
let {id, keywordID, name} = keywordProfileInstance[0];
keywordProfileID.resolve({id, keyID:keywordID, name});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input and help. I managed to sort it out using A.I.S's suggestions. But I like your line of thought!

Answer (score 0):

you should try this. hope it will work

```
function getKeywordProfiles(brandProfilesArray) {
  var array = [];
  brandProfilesArray.forEach(function (profile) {
      var data = findKeywordProfile(profile.id); 
      array.push(data);
  })
  return $q.all(array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input and help. I managed to sort it out using A.I.S's suggestions.